# How to fix java.lang.module.findexception and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I've been trying to make a speech recognition program with CMU sphinx- and sphinx-5 real alpha. I am doing this following a tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8vsXKFTee0&t=216s.
I did the exact same thing the youtuber did but I did not get the expected results. I did not have any errors in any project folders but when I run it the following is shown in the console.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for D:\eclipse workspace\SimpleSphinxCalculator\resources\libraries\sphinx4-core-5prealpha-20160628.232526-10.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sphinx4.core.5prealpha: Invalid module name: '5prealpha' is not a Java identifier
```

and nothing else. I also went through the internet finding solution and I deleted the .metadata folder and restarted the IDE and still no luck. I am using eclipse for Java developers 2020.
Somebody please help me I've been doing this as a side project for 2 years.

Comment: Does deleting your `module-info.java` file (in case you have one) and moving that JAR from the Modulepath to the Classpath (in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_) fix your issue?

Comment: Yes! that was it. Thanks a lot @howlger.

Comment: Tkx, bro. That's tip solved my issue too.